# I need sql query to merge info from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

i`m new in SQL and i need a tip. I got 2 tables ( employee and department ),

employee table as E:
id (int), name(nvarchar), gender(nvarchar), departmentID(int), dateofbirth(datetime)
department table as D : 
dep_id(int),  name(nvarchar), location(nvarchar), boss_id(int)

That`s what i need as output table:

E.id / E.name / D.name / D.location / (and last which i cant get with simple join is:) D.boss.name (not simple boss id but real employee name from E table)

Just simple question for advanced people :-)

Comment: errr...confused.  What table is boss_name in? (d.boss.name implies you have a name column in a table called boss in the 'D' schema...doesn't seem right)

Comment: i intended to say that boss name is in employee table. Boss_id reveals which employee is boss in departmend and others just workers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table a second time for the boss. (This is assuming that `boss_id` FK's to `Employee`)

```
SELECT
    E.Id,
    E.Name,
    D.Name,
    D.Location,
    B.Name
FROM Employee E
    INNER JOIN Department D on E.DepartmentID = D.Dep_id
    INNER JOIN Employee B ON D.Boss_id = B.Id
```

Comment: thanks, what if i want add a case which checks if that employee is boss in that department and changes value to null or to string 'boss in' + d.name

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query using cte as well:

```
WITH CTE AS(
Select 
e.ID,
e.name,
d.boss_id,
d.Location as DepartmentLocation,
d.name as DepartmentName
From Employee e
INNER JOIN Department d on d.boss_id =E.id
)
Select c.id, c.name, e.name as BossName, c.DepartmentLocation, c.DepartmentName

from cte c 
Inner Join Employee e1 on e1.id=c.boss_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT e.Id, e.Name, d.Name, d.Location,
(
SELECT e2.Name
FROM tblEmployee as e2
WHERE e2.id = d.boss_id
) AS [Boss name]
FROM tblEmployee as e 
INNER JOIN tblDepartment as d
ON e.DepartmentID = d.dep_ID
```

Comment: This just converts to a left join, so why not write it as a left join. It's cleaner that way.